# chrome.identity do not work without "key" in manifest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I try to make correct authorization in Chrome App. I followed official tutorial, but I was not able to sign in - every try ended with redirection to settings page and communicate that

> Account sign-in details are out of date.  Sign in again

After signing in, I got redirection once again to setting page, and after a moment, the same situation happened.

I saw in `chrome://identity-internals` that token expiration date is set on 0 of Unix time, so it seems error. 
I decided to try samples from Google Chrome Github. I installed the GDrive one and it worked fine - till the moment I deleted key from manifest, I found in documentation that this is kind of extension id. Without it, situation is identical to this with my own app. This happens in all samples with chrome.identity - without key, they are unusable, with key works fine.

Had anyone ever similar problem? Maybe this is connected to some kind of additional Origin in Cloud Console? I am not able to find any information about it. I use key from Web Application App, cause when I try to register Chrome Extension I always receive

> Invalid appId for type CHROME_EXTENSION:

but in documentation of Chrome Apps is written that I should Web Aplication Keys.

Would be great if anyone could help. I use latest Dev Channel normal Chrome and Canary, same problem on both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, the key needs to be there for the API to work. See http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.html for all the details.